# How to recursively print xml tree attributes and elements using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, printing, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file and need to store the author's attributes and the children's elements in variables and print them out on the console. So basically: id, obs, and responsible as well as FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME need to be stored as variables and printed to the console.

```
    <AUTHORS>
        <AUTHOR id='_03131488' obs='0' responsible='1'>
            <LASTNAME>Richard</LASTNAME>
            <FIRSTNAME>Dickson</FIRSTNAME>
        </AUTHOR>
        <AUTHOR id='_03135122' obs='0'>
            <LASTNAME>Carlo</LASTNAME>
            <FIRSTNAME>Ancelotti</FIRSTNAME>
        </AUTHOR>
        <AUTHOR id='_0312C456' obs='0' responsible='1'>
            <LASTNAME>Patricia</LASTNAME>
            <FIRSTNAME>Howard</FIRSTNAME>
        </AUTHOR>
    </AUTHORS>
```

I have the following code written for it but somehow it doesn't print to console at all.

```
    class Solution
    {
        public static string xmlFilePath = "authors.xml";
    
        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
            List<Author> authors = LoadAuthors(doc.Descendants("AUTHOR")
                .Elements("AUTHORS"));
        }
    
        public static List<Author> LoadAuthors(IEnumerable<XElement> authors)
        {
            return authors.Select(x => new Author()
            {
                FirstName = x.Attribute("FIRSTNAME").Value,
                LastName = x.Attribute("LASTNAME").Value,
                Children = LoadAuthors(x.Elements("AUTHORS"))
            }).ToList();
        }
    
        public void PrintAutors()
        {
            foreach (Author author in authors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(author.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Author
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Author> Children { get; set; }
    
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{FirstName}, {LastName}\n{Children
                .Select(c => c.ToString())
                .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "\n" + b)}";
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me with properly storing the values onto the variables and printing them to the console?

Comment: You are not calling `PrintAutors` anywhere, which should probably have a parameter `authors`

Comment: @Charlieface How would I do that?

Comment: In `Main()` maybe???

Comment: @Charlieface I am new to C# so I am confused about how to invoke that call in the main method?

Comment: That is not a recursion ... its just an iterative loop. Please change the title to not confuse people. A recursion is, when a function calls itself. e.E 'How to loop through xml elements'

Answer (score 1):

*"@Charlieface I am new to C# so I am confused about how to invoke that call in the main method?"*

It could look like these two modifications:

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
            List<Author> authors = LoadAuthors(doc.Descendants("AUTHOR")
                .Elements("AUTHORS"));
            // New Line in Main() as suggested by @Charlieface
            PrintAutors(authors); 
        }

        // so that the signature of PrintAutors() would change a little
        private static void PrintAutors(IList<Author> authors)
        {
            foreach (Author author in authors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(author.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gives the name "authors" doesn't exist in the current context error in the main method.

Comment: As a Compiler message, not a run-time `Exception`? That looks a little odd to me, since the second line of your code in Main() does create that _name_, doesn't it: `List<Author> authors = LoadAuthors(doc.Descendants("AUTHOR").Elements("AUTHORS"));`

Comment: It's not a Case Sensitivity issue?

Comment: ... or rather a `static` issue - somehow all your methods in your class seem to be `public static` - except the previously unused `PrintAutors()`, see also the edited answer

Comment: ... suggesting to have a `private static void PrintAutors(...` rather than `public void...` (non-static)